# Fetch data with image to Laravel API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fetch-api

There is a problem when trying to send data including an img using fetch() to my Laravel API.

For a strange reason, trying to use FormData isn't working because the data is not received from the API.

This is my controller in Laravel, which is waiting for a JSON

```
public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        dd($request)
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $imginput = $request->file('image');
            $imgExtension = $imginput->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Generar un nombre único para el archivo
            $uniqueFileName = uniqid('imagen_') . '.' . $imgExtension;
            // Mover el archivo al directorio de destino con el nombre único
            $imginput->move(public_path('img/products'), $uniqueFileName);
        //     // Ahora, $uniqueFileName contiene el nombre único del archivo
        }
        $product->provider_id = $request->provider_id;
        $product->reference = $request->reference;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->description = $request->description;
        $product->stock = $request->stock;
        $product->price = $request->price;
        $product->discount = $request->discount;
        $product->tax = $request->tax;
        $product->image ='img/products/' . $uniqueFileName;
        $product->param_size  = $request->param_size;
        $product->param_gender  = $request->param_gender;
        $product->param_subcategory  = $request->param_subcategory;
        $product->param_color   = $request->param_color;
        $product->param_state  = $request->param_state;
        $product->save();    // save
        $data[] = $product;
        if ($data == null) {
            return OS::frontendResponse('404', 'error',  $data, $msg = 'Producto no actualizado.');
        } else {
            return OS::frontendResponse('200', 'success', $data, $msg = 'Producto actualizado correctamente.');
        }
    }
```

The dd($request) result:

```
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#36
    #parameters: []
  }
```

This was trying to do it with the FormData(form). Trying without it and getting every input with getElementbyId, this is the result:

```
  +attributes: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#46
    #parameters: []
  }
  +request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\InputBag {#36
    #parameters: array:15 [
      "provider_id" => "2"
      "reference" => "REF3546"
      "name" => "New Balance Athletics Amplified"
      "description" => "Blusa corto para mujer"
      "stock" => "10"
      "price" => "150"
      "discount" => "10"
      "tax" => "19"
      "image" => []
      "param_size" => "1520"
      "param_gender" => "1602"
      "param_subcategory" => "1761"
      "param_mark" => "243"
      "param_color" => "1620"
      "param_state" => "1651"
    ]
  }
```

As you can see, it's not getting the image, but in my console.log(data):

```
{provider_id: '2', reference: 'REF3546', name: 'New Balance Athletics Amplified', description: 'Blusa corto para mujer', stock: '10', …}
description: "Blusa corto para mujer"
discount: "10"
image: File {name: 'Falda_de_Tenis_Club_Negro_HS1454_01_laydown.jpeg', lastModified: 1693944039182, lastModifiedDate: Tue Sep 05 2023 15:00:39 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Colombia), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 5508, …}
name: "New Balance Athletics Amplified"
param_color: "1620"
param_gender: "1602"
param_mark: "243"
param_size: "1520"
param_state: "1651"
param_subcategory: "1761"
price: "150"
provider_id: "2"
reference: "REF3546"
stock: "10"
tax: "19"
[[Prototype]]: 'Object'
```

This is my JavaScript:

```
let apiKey = "EXaR0JoKIirohPwbRPIHc3s73Oygi0XV";
let urlParams = "http://localhost/api/public/api/params/";
let urlProvider = "http://localhost/api/public/api/providers/";
let urlProducts = "http://localhost/api/public/api/products/";
let providerSelect = document.getElementById("Provider");

let reference = document.getElementById("Reference");
let namee = document.getElementById("Name");
let description = document.getElementById("Description");
let stock = document.getElementById("Stock");
let price = document.getElementById("Price");
let discount = document.getElementById("Discount");
let tax = document.getElementById("Tax");
let provider=document.getElementById("Provider");
let size = document.getElementById("Size");
let gender = document.getElementById("Gender");
let subcategory = document.getElementById("Subcategory");
let mark = document.getElementById("Mark");
let color = document.getElementById("Color");
let state = document.getElementById("State");

const valores = window.location.search;
const urlData = new URLSearchParams(valores);
var id = urlData.get('id');


function fillSelect(selectElement, data, paramtype_id) {
    const paramsOfType = data.filter(param => param.paramtype_id === paramtype_id);

    paramsOfType.forEach(param => {
        let option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = param.id;
        option.textContent = param.name;
        selectElement.appendChild(option);
    });
}

const file = document.getElementById('foto');
const foto = document.getElementById('agregar-img-produc');
file.addEventListener('change', e => {
    if (e.target.files[0]) {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            foto.src = e.target.result;
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
    }
});

let paramsData;
let providersData;
let productData;

fetchDataFromAPI(urlProvider, apiKey)
    .then(data => {
        providersData = data.data;
        
        providersData.forEach(provider => {
            let option = document.createElement('option');
            option.value = provider.id;
            option.textContent = provider.legal_name;
            providerSelect.appendChild(option);
        });
    })
    .then(() => {

        return fetchDataFromAPI(urlParams, apiKey);
    })
    .then(data => {
        paramsData = data.data;

        fillSelect(color, paramsData, 8);
        fillSelect(state, paramsData, 9);
        fillSelect(size, paramsData, 6);
        fillSelect(gender, paramsData, 7);
        fillSelect(subcategory, paramsData, 13);
        fillSelect(mark, paramsData, 4);
    })
    .then(() => {

        return fetchDataFromAPI(urlProducts, apiKey, id);
    })
    .then(data => {
        productData = data.data[0];
        reference.value = productData.reference;
        namee.value = productData.name;
        description.value = productData.description;
        stock.value = productData.stock;
        price.value = productData.price;
        discount.value = productData.discount;
        tax.value = productData.tax;
        provider.value = productData.provider_id;
        size.value = productData.param_size;
        gender.value = productData.param_gender;
        subcategory.value = productData.param_subcategory;
        mark.value = productData.param_mark;
        color.value = productData.param_color;
        state.value = productData.param_state;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });

let form = document.getElementById("productForm");


form.addEventListener("submit", async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // let formData = new FormData();
    let selectedFile = document.getElementById("foto").files[0];

    
    let data = {
        provider_id: provider.value,
        reference: reference.value,
        name: namee.value,
        description: description.value,
        stock: stock.value,
        price: price.value,
        discount: discount.value,
        tax: tax.value,
        image: selectedFile,
        param_size: size.value,
        param_gender: gender.value,
        param_subcategory: subcategory.value,
        param_mark: mark.value,
        param_color: color.value,
        param_state: state.value,
    };

    console.log(data);
    

    updateDataToAPI(urlProducts, id, apiKey, data)
    .then(responseData => {
        console.log('Respuesta del servidor:', responseData);
    }).catch((error) => { 
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
});
```

This is the function updateDataToAPI() that's called from another JavaScript file:

```
function updateDataToAPI(url, id, apiKey, data) {
    return fetch(url + id + '?key=' + apiKey, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    }).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        return Promise.reject(error); // Devuelve una promesa rechazada en caso de error
    });
}
```

This is my form if you're interested:

```
<?php
require_once('resources/initiator.php');
if ($_SESSION['type_user'] != 235 && $_SESSION['type_user'] != 99999999) {
    header("Location: home.php");
}
?>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../slick/slick-theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/edit-product.css">


<?php
require_once('resources/template-crud.php')
?>

<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-xl-10 pt-2">
    <div class="card-header p-3">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-center">
                <!-- Texto de editar perfil -->
                <h1>EDITAR PRODUCTO</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-crud">

        <form id="productForm" method="POST" class="br container p-4 mb-5" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center  ">

                        <div class=" image-container">
                            <div class=" space-slider2marc">

                                <div class="single-item  slider3mar"
                                    data-slick='{"slidesToShow": 1, "slidesToScroll": 1}'>

                                    <div class="card-slider-mar" href="#">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <img class="img-slider-cat" src="../img/carru3.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center btn-elim-img">
                                            <a href="" class="btn botones-crud">Eliminar</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="card-slider-mar" href="#">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <img class="img-slider-cat" src="../img/carru3.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center btn-elim-img">
                                            <a href="" class="btn botones-crud">Eliminar</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-slider-mar" href="#">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <img class="img-slider-cat" src="../img/carru3.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center btn-elim-img">
                                            <a href="" class="btn botones-crud">Eliminar</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-slider-mar" href="#">
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                                            <img class="img-slider-cat" src="../img/carru3.jpg" alt="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center btn-elim-img">
                                            <a href="" class="btn botones-crud">Eliminar</a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <br>
                        <!-- Botón de agregar imágenes abajo -->

                        <input type="file" id="foto" name="image" accept="image/*">
                        <!-- <button class="btn  botones-crud" id="agregar-img-produc">Agregar Imagen</button> -->
                        <label class="btn botones-crud mt-3" type="button" id="agregar-img-produc" for="foto">Nueva Imagen</label>
                        <div class="error-message" id="img-error"></div>

                        <br>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Reference" class="form-label"> Referencia</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Reference" name="reference">
                            <div class="error-message" id="reference-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Provider" class="form-label">Proveedores</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="Provider" name="Provider">
                               

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="provider-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Name" class="form-label">Nombre del Producto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" name="name">
                            <div class="error-message" id="name-error"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Description" class="form-label "> Descripción</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control descripcion-product" id="Description"
                                name="description">
                            <div class="error-message" id="description-error"></div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>





                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center">

                        <!-- formulario parte derecha -->


                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Stock" class="form-label"> Existencias</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Stock" name="stock">
                            <div class="error-message" id="stock-error"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Price" class="form-label"> Precio</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Price" name="price">
                            <div class="error-message" id="price-error"></div>
                        </div>



                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Discount" class="form-label"> Descuento</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Discount" name="discount">
                            <div class="error-message" id="discount-error"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Tax" class="form-label"> Impuesto</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tax" name="tax">
                            <div class="error-message" id="tax-error"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Size" class="form-label">Talla</label>
                            <select class="form-select " id="Size" name="param_size">
                                
                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="size-error"></div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Gender" class="form-label">Genero</label>
                            <select class="form-select " id="Gender" name="param_gender">
                               

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="gender-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Subcategory" class="form-label">Subcategoria</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="Subcategory" name="param_subcategory">
                              

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="subcategory-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Mark" class="form-label">Marca</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="Mark" name="param_mark">
                                

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="mark-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="Color" class="form-label">Color</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="Color" name="param_color">
                           

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="color-error"></div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-8">
                            <label for="State" class="form-label">Estado</label>
                            <select class="form-select" id="State" name="param_state">
                               

                            </select>
                            <div class="error-message" id="state-error"></div>

                        </div>




                        <div class="container d-flex flex-column align-items-center mt-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn botones-crud">Guardar</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
require_once('resources/footer.php')
?>

<script src="../js/edit-product.js"></script>
<script src="../js/sliders.js"></script>
<script src="../js/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="../js/fetchs/crud-edit-product.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

PD: It's a project being done with my junior's developers teammates, so all critics are welcome.

Comment: Since your sending a file, the content type should be `multipart/form-data` right ?